# Is there a substance that is hard (ideally abrasive) in solid form but would dissolve in water?

Tags: aqueous-solution, solubility, solid-state-chemistry

doing some research for a dishwasher / dish cleaning product and interested in any compounds that could be fashioned into a brush or other abrasive form and then dissolve and wash away with the water cycle?

Comment: Would simple granulated salt work? Toxicity sounds like an issue for some stuff.

Answer (score 1):

A usual cleaning product that does not pose any health hazard and that is easily washed away is sodium hydrogenocarbonate (aka baking soda). I use it myself, and it works a charm in the kitchen!